# D3 - elements are added but `.append("path")` next in the chain is never executed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The issue is I'm trying to build a pie chart, I add the data, `enter`, append a `g` element for each item of data, then add a click handler, after adding the click handler nothing else is executed.

```js
const pie = g.selectAll("path")
  .data(pie(chartData))
  .enter()
  .append("g") // <--- this works fine, elements are appended
  .on("click", (d, i) => onSliceClick(i)) // <--- click handler appears to be added fine
  .append("path") // <--- this and nothing beneath it are executed
```

Having a very hard time debugging as the issue does not appear locally, discerning any difference is very hard right now. I am hoping someone with more experience with D3.js could explain some more general scenarios where a chained method may not be reach and no errors are thrown.

I have been debugging in Chrome and when I place breakpoints across the line they all trigger, but the breakpoint after the `.on("click", ...` handler is never executed.

[image: chrome debugger]

In the above image, breakpoint on ln 84215 is never reached, however all the breakpoints on the line above are executed.

Comment: Is the missing `"` accurate or a typo on the question: `"click, ...`?

Comment: @AndrewReid unfortunately not, code was on my work computer and I made an error typing it across. Syntax is fine, have updated the example

Comment: Ah, didn't think that was it, would've caused errors, don't suppose you can make a functioning minimal example replicating the problem?

Comment: Your question is inconsitent: in your code snippet you claim that the last `.append()` was never executed, in your image, however, the problematic breakpoint on line 84215 refers to code within the click handler which is a totally different thing. Can you clarify?